# How to sort data stored in a text file by high score in c#

Tags: c#, text-files, leaderboard

I am making a quiz game for my computing coursework and I have completed the quiz part of my application and I am currently moving on to my leader board but to do that I need to sort my scores text file which contains the users name, score and time but I am now trying to retrieve these data and display them in a table.

The users' name score and time saves fine into the scores text file but to display these details I first need to order these details by the score.

My test file is organised like this:

```
username,score,time

userName1,33,12
userName2,-55,33
userName3,34,2
userName4,23,27
userName5,63,72
```

This is the code that I am currently using but this only works if I have the data in the text file sorted first.

```
string[] readFile = File.ReadAllLines(file).ToArray();

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    string[] userDetails = File.ReadAllLines(file).ToArray();

    string username = userDetails[0];
    string score = userDetails[1];

    // Apply the text of lblUsername1-5 to be what the names 
    // of the top 5 scorers are in the file.
    lblUsername1.Text = userDetails[0].Split(',')[0];
    lblUsername2.Text = userDetails[1].Split(',')[0];
    lblUsername3.Text = userDetails[2].Split(',')[0];
    lblUsername4.Text = userDetails[3].Split(',')[0];
    lblUsername5.Text = userDetails[4].Split(',')[0];

    // Apply the text of lblScore1-5 to be what the scores 
    // of the top 5 scorers are in the file.
    lblScore1.Text = userDetails[0].Split(',')[1];
    lblScore2.Text = userDetails[1].Split(',')[1];
    lblScore3.Text = userDetails[2].Split(',')[1];
    lblScore4.Text = userDetails[3].Split(',')[1];
    lblScore5.Text = userDetails[4].Split(',')[1];
}
```

So if some one could help me to sort the data in my scores ext file that would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The task is much easier to accomplish using serialization rather than parsing and chopping up text lines. Otherwise read file, parse to a class, sort the collection, rewrite the file

Answer (score 1):

You can use linq to sort data from your file

```
string[][] userDetails = File.ReadAllLines(file).Select(s => s.Split(',')).OrderBy(arr => int.TryParse(arr[1], out int result) ? result : 0)).Take(5).ToArray();

lblUsername1.Text = userDetails[0][0];
lblUsername2.Text = userDetails[1][0];
lblUsername3.Text = userDetails[2][0];
lblUsername4.Text = userDetails[3][0];
lblUsername5.Text = userDetails[4][0];

// Apply the text of lblScore1-5 
// to be what the scores of the top 5 scorers are in the file.
lblScore1.Text = userDetails[0][1];
lblScore2.Text = userDetails[1][1];
lblScore3.Text = userDetails[2][1];
lblScore4.Text = userDetails[3][1];
lblScore5.Text = userDetails[4][1];``
```

Comment: You shouldn't code by exception. Try this instead: `.OrderBy(arr => int.TryParse(arr[1], out int result) ? result : 0)`

Answer (score 0):

You should use objects to manage this. Your class should be a user with properties, se below.

Now you have full control on sorting and managing of your objects

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }
    public int Time { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //This you get from file, no need for this in your code            
        string[] fromFile = new string[5] 
        { "userName1,33,12", "userName2,-55,33", "userName3,34,2", "userName4,23,27", "userName5,63,72" };    

        List<User> users = new List<User>();

        foreach (string line in fromFile)
        {
            string[] splitLine = line.Split(',');
            users.Add(new User() { Name = splitLine[0], Score = int.Parse(splitLine[1]), Time = int.Parse(splitLine[2]) });    
        }    

        foreach (User oneUser in users.OrderByDescending(x => x.Score))
        {
            //Here the store to file or what you want to do
        }
    }
}
```